# Hide Navbar on some routes (React Router v5)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

hope you're having a good day.

I'm having a problem where I have 10+ routes that I do wish to have a navbar and 2 routes where I do NOT wish to have the navbar. This is the way I have my route setup as of now.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      /* My routes with the navbar here */
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Now how would I go about placing the routes that I do not wish to have the navbar? sorry if I described this poorly just ask in the comments and I will explain further. thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: How about using the context api, set hide or show inside each route by calling a method that sets a state variable in your provider and then use that variable as a conditional around Navbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like this isn't the best way to do it but you *could* use the context api to hide/show the nav per route

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-jm1vf

In this example the /about route hides the nav